# Can one VBA code execute commands in excel and access?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Is it possible for one VBA code to execute commands in both excel and access?

Each day I have about 15 queries that need to be copy/pasted into specific sheets and places in an excel workbook.  The information in the queries is updated everyday.  I'm hoping to write a code that could insert the results of these queries into their specific locations in excel.

Would it be possible to write one code to do all of this?

Comment: Sure. You could even run both from Word's VBA. Use ADO or DAO to connect to Access from Excel or an Excel.Application object to connect to Excel from Access.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Access maintains spreadsheet output capabilities including:

1. [TransferSpreadsheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff844793.aspx) where you simply identify the query to be exported and outputted to a specific workbook and range: `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "qryName", "C:\Path\To\Excelspread\sheet.xlsx" True, "!WorksheetName"`
2. [CopyFromRecordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff839240.aspx) where you declare your queries in DAO or ADO recordsets in VBA and output resultset to a worksheet range: `ws.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst`

Do note you never really need to *run* queries in Access except if they are action queries (append, update, delete). But for select queries, anytime it is in use (exported, called, or opened) query runs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. It will only run in one application.

However, you can create an instance of an Excel application inside Access and perform pretty much the same via Access VBA. Plus, the syntax is the same.

For example, this creates a new Excel application:

```
Dim xl As New Excel.Application
```

From it, you can do things such as `xl.Workbooks.Open(...)`.